# Not sure how to make the topology uniform

Tags: modeling, faces, topology, zbrush

I have a staff that I am creating and wanting to import into Zbrush, but I am having a hard time getting a good topology on the faces of this staff. Is there any way to make the faces into quads or a more uniform tris?[image]

Comment: Try a decimate modifier. By default, you need to be in wireframe view in object mode to see the changes in real time. Experiment with all 3 un-subdivide types, however I think "collapse" or "planar" are most likely to work for you.

Answer (score 1):

The [Remesh modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/remesh.html) is your best option to do this quickly. Turn the Octree Depth up until you have enough resolution.